# useEffect wait for a result from the async function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a function for POST request in React app (due to I need it in few places), it should return a responseText in the useEffect statement. the variant I've googled doesn't act as async - the string console.log("JSON", json) put into the console *JSON undefined* before the getting response from server...

```js
useEffect(() => {
        (async function() {
            try {
                const response = await post_return(postData);
                const json = await JSON.stringify(response);
                console.log("json", json);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        })();
    }, [postData]);
```

```js
const API_URL_REGISTRATION = "https:.....";

export function post_return (dataPost)  {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", API_URL_REGISTRATION, true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log("xhr.status", this.status);
            console.log("this.responseText", this.responseText);
            return  xhr.status
        }
    };
    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log("xhr.status", this.status);
        console.log("this.responseText", this.responseText);
        return  xhr.status;
    };

    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert('Error' + this.status);
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataPost));
}
```

tried also:

*export async function post_return (dataPost)  {...*

and:

*xhr.onreadystatechange = async function ()*

What I do wrong? 
Thanks,

Comment: is it compulsory you need to use xmlhttprequest, is that you can use inbuilt fetch ?

Comment: you can refer here, if this is fine let me know https://codesandbox.io/s/59356038-so-2kxd7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that is wrong with `post_return` function is it returns `undefined` immediately, hence the `response` variable value is actually `undefined` and a result of calling `JSON.stringify` with `undefined` is also `undefined`. What you should do is to correct `post_return` so that it returns a `Promise`.

Simplest solution would be to use built-in `fetch` like so:

```js
export function async post_return (dataPost)  {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL_REGISTRATION, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(dataPost),
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });
  
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  
  // Here you can do some basic error parsing/handling
  throw new Error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rafal2228, thanks for your post, I adopted it for my needs

```js
export async function post_return(url, dataPost) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(dataPost),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    return {
        status: response.status,
        body: json
    };
}
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
        (async function() {
            try {
                if (postData.email !== undefined)
                {
                    const response = await post_return(API_URL_REGISTRATION, postData);
                    // console.log("response", response);
                    setshowLoader(false);
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        navigate("/login")
                    } else alert(response.body);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Ошибка ' , e);
            }
        })();
    }, [postData]);
```